# Spark Application keeps on RUNNING and seems HANGING - org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I’m using HDFS 2.7.3 and Spark2 2.0.0 in Hadoop cluster. When I start Spark2 Thrift Server it successfully starts but automatically from Hive user a job starts to run and it seems to hang forever.  If I manually kill the job, again it starts a new job with a new applicationId.

[image: Before starting the Thrift server][image: After starting the Thrift server] [image: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 job hangs]

But if I stop the Spark2 Thrift Server the it kills the job. Can you please help me to understand this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i have met the same issue like you, spark 2.0 is not stable of thriftserver module, it is better to upgrade to spark 2.1